# child node of flexbox button not applying height in percentage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having following code

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background: black;
  flex-direction: row
}
.flex-item {
  height: 100%;
  background: grey
}
```

```html
<button class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    Click Me
  </div>
</button>
```

The problem is, parent node is `<button>` with `flex-direction: row`,  child element does not accept height in percentage.
height in percentage only works if parent node is `<div>`

Comment: Why you want `height: 100%`? Even if you want `height: 100%` then you should inherit the height rather than specify 100% using `height: inherit`

Comment: Do not forget that some elements by default have margin & padding + button has border

Comment: @Shiladitya awesome, how did this not come in my mind... thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background: black;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: none;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<button class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    Click Me
  </div>
</button>
```

but if you work with `flex`, it is better to use its functionality to add to the parent
`align-items: stretch;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background: black;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: none;
}

.flex-item {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<button class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    Click Me
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: This is not the solution. Click Me should get 100% of it's parent. which in your code not achieving.